# How do I safely get the materials around a black hole in EVERSPACE?

Tags: everspace

A few zones in EVERSPACE feature a Black Hole, with a number of rare materials in a ring around the center. Important materials like Dark Matter, Dark Energy, Components, Powercells, what have you. If I get too close, I tend to struggle getting away from the black hole, which I'm sure is by design. I haven't died to one yet, but I usually manage to grab only one of the material pickups before I'm far too sweaty to attempt another pass. Therefore...

**How do I efficiently and safely collect the materials around a Black Hole?**